# Gluon SceneBuilder won't open the FXML files while IntellijIDEA is open

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I have installed both SceneBuilder 11.0.0 and 8.5.0 (not at the same time) and I encountered the problem with both versions. The first time I used the 11 version, it worked fine 1 or 2 times when I opened fxml files from intellij, then, after trying to open the files and nothing happening I closed the IDE and SceneBuilder opened up right away.

I am using Java 8 for the project, thus I downloaded the 8.5 version.  I have also tried opening SceneBuilder, then Intellij and then the fxml files, but again, it worked just one time, now it won't open any files.

Also, I can't even open the app by itself while intellij is running. I have updated intellij recently so the version is not outdated, what should I do?

Comment: Which OS are you using? I have a similar issue with Eclipse on Mac. Before I can open an FXML from Eclipse I have to explicitly close SceneBuilder (the app and not just the window).

Comment: @mipa i am using Windows 10

Comment: Same for me. Not using it.